# Auth guard not working in angular 5

Tags: angular, authentication, angular-router-guards

Here is my static login service

```
login(email: string, password: string) {
debugger;
const user = {
  username: email,
  password: password,

};
if (email === "admin" && password === "admin") {
  localStorage.setItem("currentUser", JSON.stringify(user));
}
if (localStorage.getItem("currentUser")) {
  // logged in so return true
  return user;
} else {
  return false;
}
}
```

My authguard service

```
  export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router) {


  }
        isAuthenticated(): boolean{
      if (localStorage.getItem("currentUser")) {
        return true;
      }
      else{
        return false;
      }
    }

    canActivate(): boolean {
      if (!this.isAuthenticated()) {
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
}
```

my app.routing.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: "home", component: HomeComponent ,canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  { path: "login", component: AuthComponent },
  { path: "", component: AuthComponent },
  { path: "employees", component: EmpComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  // otherwise redirect to home
  { path: "**", redirectTo: "/" }
];
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, HeaderComponent, FooterComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    SharedModule,
    HomeModule,
    AuthModule,
    EmpModule,
    routing,
    Ng4LoadingSpinnerModule,
    AlertModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [AuthGuard, AuthenticationService],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

I just tested this by entering a route directly in browser url for example /home which has canactivate enabled in its route config but when i do so the home contents are displayed instead of redirecting to the login page.Need too know what's wrong here any help will be really appreciated thanks in advance :)

Comment: i think the issue is local storage has values always, clear it and test

Comment: @Sajeetharan i have not logged in just typed the route in browser url which have canactivate enabled.So there is no values in localstorage.

Comment: strange, can i see your full code

Comment: you already have that here!

Comment: what i meant was to debug

Comment: @Sajeetharan what file you need in full ? Also i don't get any console errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160834/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-melvin).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no issue with your current code, if you have **`routing`** for each component separately, remove them and have them only in the **`app.module.ts`**

Answer (score 1):

if you re using the route guard add it inside root app.module or what ever module.ts file

```
providers: [AuthGuard]
```